# creating python virtual environment on windows 7

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I wanted to create a python virtual environment in Windows 7.
I have installed activepython 2.7 32 bit version and installed virtualev using pip command.  After that I created a folder named "virtualenv", on drive C.  For that folder I have executed the following command.

```
virtualenv <virtualenv-name>
```

While executing this command it opens a python file named `virtualenv.py`. While closing the file, it does not prompt to be saved.

While checking on `C:\virtualenv\`  I was not getting the virtual environment that I tried to create.

Answer (score 0):

From command line execute:

```
virtualenv MY_ENV
```

It will create a virtual env in `MY_ENV` folder. Than activate it:

```
MY_ENV\Scripts\activate
```

Also check the [virtualenv user guide](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#usage).

Comment: i tried the above method that you have given but instead of creating the virtual environment , it opened a python file called virtualenv.py, nothing else happened ,  i tried it on a windows 7 machine .

Answer (score 0):

```
conda create --name myvirtualenv python=2.7 numpy
```

This will create a virtual environment of python 2.7 with just numpy or pandas or the full package based on the parameter

Answer (score 0):

First, open cmd and go to the directory where you want your virtual env to be present.
while writing this I have 3.7.5 python installed on my PC.
write below command on cmd.
py -m venv.
for activation of the virtual environment.
open Scripts folder and click on activate file,
for reference visit this website https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).